# unable to render Č character in pdf

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017, itext

Expected Output:

```
Čairo
```

Reality:

```
airo
```

I am initializing the font like so:

```
        Dim cb As PdfContentByte = writer.DirectContent

        cb.BeginText()
        Dim bf As BaseFont
        bf = BaseFont.CreateFont("c:\windows\fonts\arial.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED)
```

I've tried to do it like this as well:

```
            Dim f As New Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 10.0F, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)
            Dim ph As New Phrase(moderate_foods(i), f)
            Dim cell As New PdfPCell(ph)
```

**How do we render the Č character in a pdf?**

Comment: The answer to this question can also be found on the official web site, for instance by searching on the keyword [czech](https://developers.itextpdf.com/tags/czech). Please note that you're using an old version of iText (version 5 or earlier). You should consider upgrading to iText 7.